# How to get the last inserted id to store array of images into db in laravel?

Tags: php, arrays

**Controller code:**

```
public function saveImages(Request $imagesform){


   $input=$imagesform->input('images');

   $images=array();
  if($files=$imagesform->file('images')){
    foreach($files as $file){
        $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move('image',$name);
        $images[]=$name;
    }
  }




  photosModel::insert( [
 'imagesid' =>$this->getimageId(),
    'uploadedImages'=>  implode("|",$images),
    'imagesid' =>$this->getimageId(),
          ]);



  return redirect('formImages');

 }
```

This is my controller code to store array of images,but here,each image gets a unique id, I don't want it. When I store array of images ,all the images should get stored based on one unique id.

Also,I want to store these array of images in storage folder.

**View:**

```
    <label id="show" for="files" class="button">Upload photo</label>
    <input id="files" name="images[]" style="visibility:hidden;" 
    type="file" multiple>
    <input type="submit" name="Save" id="imgsave" value="SAVE">
```